# How to pass list of existing locales into dropdown menu

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to pass get all existing locales to view. This is my code

view

```
{!! Form::select('language', $languages,null, ['placeholder' => 'Pick a language']) !!}
```

controller

this only pull the current how can I pull all with eloquent

```
 $languageCurrent = App::getLocale();
```

How can I pass it into view(when I'm manipulating data from database I can return with something like this)

```
->with('users', $users)
```

How can I return value as array

Comment: `App::getLocale()` has nothing to do with Eloquent. Where are your available locales stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple locales defined in `config/app.php`, like described [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/tips/example-on-how-to-use-multiple-locales-in-your-laravel-5-website):

```
'locales' => ['en' => 'English', 'sv' => 'Swedish'],
```

You could try to do this:

```
{!! Form::select('language', array_flip(config('app.locales')), null, ['placeholder' => 'Pick a language']) !!}
```

`config()` will get locales list and [`array_flip()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) will swap keys and values for `Form::select`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an array in `/config/app.php` containing the locales which you use, for example : `'locales' => ['en' => 'English', 'pl' => 'Polish']` than you should be able to use `config()` helper function to get the values like `$available_locales=config('app.locales');`